# Word2Vec + Regression - Numerical scoring method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, word2vec

I would like to build a neural network with groups of words and numerical values as inputs and a numerical value as output.

For this purpose, I think the most proper solution would be to use the Word2Vec algorithm on the groups of words in order to get embeddings and then to train a neural network (probably a LSTM one) with them and other inputs/outputs.

But how to achieve that please? 
Since there is one vector of weights for each word (thank to the Word2Vec algorithm), how to train a neural network to predict numerical values (a regression in other words)? 
Or at least, how could I transform this vector of weights into a meaningful numerical value? (I actually don't know how to train a neural network with vectors of numerical values and "simple" numerical values together.)

I tried to check thoses concepts out on the Web but I haven't found very relevant  articles for my purpose. Some of them are:

-Word embeddings with logistic regression

-https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras

-https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8eb6/74c76fc471e9cf815921b6329eb4a1bbed30.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use a distance algorithm like [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) to calculate the distances between the vectors. 
The shorter the distance the more similar your words are.